# Implementing LDAP (preferably OpenLDAP) 'tiered' server

Tags: authentication, ldap, openldap

I'm trying to set up an LDAP server which has a local database of some users, but will refer the request to another 'parent' server if the record is not found on it's own database. The records would not have a different suffix, just that the userid would be different. I have read lots about referrals, chaining, master/slave, producer/consumer, etc. However, I cannot work out which is the right solution for me as there is a lot of differing confusing documentation. I am only a user of the 'parent' server, so would prefer not to have to change any settings on it. I would like to use OpenLDAP or an equivalent FOSS solution.

Thanks!

Comment: You've been reading the wrong things. You should have been reading about translucent proxying. Off topic.

Comment: @EJP thanks - will this also work for records not in the remote database? I have read that it can add/modify attributes. Apologies - Server Fault next time...